# How to unzip data coming from Google Cloud PubSub using Dataflow (Java SDK)

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

I have a Dataflow pipeline streaming compressed data(bzip) from cloud pubsub. Can any one help to suggest a way to uncompress the data.

Comment: Is there anything preventing you from writing a DoFn in your pipeline that uses some regular Java library for bzip2 decompression, e.g. https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-compress/?

Comment: In the newer versions of Dataflow based on Beam, there is a [PubsubMessage](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/sdks/javadoc/2.1.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/gcp/pubsub/PubsubMessage.html) class, which makes the payload available as a `byte[]`. This can be used with any standard decompression library to decompress the byte array.

Comment: @BenChambers: Thanks for the suggestion. I implemented using the PubsubMessage class and got the desired result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the newer versions of Dataflow based on Beam, there is a PubsubMessage class, which makes the payload available as a byte[]. This can be accessed within a `DoFn` and passed to any standard decompression library, such as [commons-compress](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-compress/) to output the decompressed result.